# How to appear TIN field CRM module in odoo10?

Tags: odoo

I am new user of odoo10 development.I want to appear `TIN` field in CRM module for `odoo10`. How should I do? In `odoo11`, TIN field is already appeared in CRM module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tax Identification Number TIN is a base field named "vat" in res.partner model in both Odoo 10 and 11. It is specified in Odoo 11 res.partner form view but not in Odoo 10. This is why it is not visible in 10.

You can make a modification yourself to the Odoo 10 form by adding the field. You can add it the same way it is done in Odoo 10:

`<field name="vat" placeholder="e.g. BE0477472701"/>`

Note that the field name is "vat" and the field caption is "TIN". The right way to make modifications to Odoo base views is to inherit from them, not to modify directly them. If you modify them directly, your modifications will be overridden when you update Odoo.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
  <record id="view_partner_form2" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form2</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"></field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
             
              
              <field name="vat" placeholder="e.g. BE0477472701"/>

            
            </field>
  </record>  
</odoo>

Comment: Should I modifty like this in my custom moudule?

Comment: Almost there. Add xpath element for the vat field to tell where in the base view you want the new vat field to appear and you are done: The content of the arch will be like this: 
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='website']" position="before">
        <field name="vat" placeholder="e.g. BE0477472701"/>
    </xpath>
. This xpath adds the field before the website field.